# Edit not related to the first question

Tags: discussion

What should I do when the OP edit his question and add another one that's not related totally to the first one, do I have to answer his seconds question too Or ask him to create another one ? What are you suggesting ?

Related post: [RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: [object Object] error express 4.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448321/rangeerror-err-http-invalid-status-code-invalid-status-code-object-object/48448378)

Comment: This is as horrible as a question that keeps getting edited to reflect an evolving understanding. At least a straight-up full edit can get – and yes, *must* be – rolled back.